# Vue component with v-for very slow to render and load the first byte

Tags: performance, vue.js, rendering, nuxt.js, v-for

I have a vue component with v-for that has about 4 or 5 rows only, and inside this component another components, all with static and simple text data. But it's taking about 10 seconds to complete rendering.

This is performance timing:

[image]

I already tried several possible solutions on vue, like `<client-only>`, `nextTick`, etc., but it didnt make difference.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more details, in particular the context, what you try to achieve, what yo did to achieve it and your previous attempts to solve your problem.